# GNUPLOT: How to set reverse HOT color palette

Tags: colors, gnuplot, palette

Here is the example in http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/pm3dcolors.html

```
set palette rgb 21,22,23; set title "hot (black-red-yellow-white)";
```

The above code set the hot palette. However I want a reversed hot palette, say:

white-yellow-red-black.

Small least value map to white and largest value map to black.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use negative numbers to invert the palette:

```
set pm3d map
set palette rgb 21,22,23
splot x
```

gives you

[image]

whereas

```
set pm3d map
set palette rgb -21,-22,-23
splot x
```

gives you

[image]

Answer (score 13):

Miguel's answer is correct. Rather than making the individual numbers negative, the command `set palette negative` also does the trick:

```
set pm3d map
set palette negative rgb 21,22,23
splot x
```

would produce what you wanted. You can split the command up too:

```
set palette rgb 21,22,23
set palette negative
```

is equivalent. You can use `set palette positive` to undo this modification, or `set palette` to restore all the defaults (including the colours). Try `help set palette` for the full list of things you can do.